# Cannot place GLSurfaceView over SurfaceView?

Tags: android

My understanding is you cannot overlay two surfaceviews in Android, based on this discussion:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/COffLpanlz0

Further evidence it this does not work:  [GLSurfaceView/SurfaceView overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870535/glsurfaceview-surfaceview-overlap?rq=1)

However I would like to know if here is a workaround? Or if perhaps this has changed with Android 4.1?

The only suggestion from google framework engineer was shown below: Does anyone know how this would be done? Or if there are any other ways to achieve this?

" It's probably not the best way, but right now you simply can not have multiple overlapping   surface views in a window, so the only way to achieve this is to render the overlay in the main window.  Fyi, using a separate thread and postInvalidate() is extra work that is not needed, just call invalidate() from the main thread.  And you'll want to make sure that at least the part of your view hierarchy involved with drawing the overlay is as simply as possible (not deep and not a lot of views to iterate over) to reduce the overhead as much as possible."
- show quoted text -
hac...@android.com

Answer (score 1):

With Android 4.0 and higher you should use a TextureView instead. You can stack as many TextureViews as you want on top of each other. You can also animate them, etc.

Comment: Can you make the background of a texture view transparent?  Is there anyway to convert an existing GLSurfaceView to a TextureView?

Comment: 4.0+ is a serious restriction ... I am wondering if there is a workaround.

Comment: The background of a TextureView can be transparent (it is by default actually.) A TextureView can be used just like a SurfaceView so you can render with OpenGL into it.